# does the size of char * (character pointer) in C/C++ vary? - use for database column fixed size

Tags: c++, mysql, c, database, pointers

per the following code, I get the size of a character pointer is 8 bytes.  Yet this [site](http://c4learn.com/c-programs/pointer-program-4-size-of-float-pointer.html)  has a size of 1 byte for the char pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>



int main(void ){

char *a = "saher asd asd asldasdas;daksd ahwal";
printf(" nSize = %d \n", sizeof(a));

return 0;

}
```

Is this always the case? I am writing a connector for a simple database I am implementing and want to read TEXT field of mysql into my database. Since TEXT has variable size, I was wondering if my column Type/metadata can have a fixed size of 8 bytes where I store the  pointer in memory to the string (char *)?

Comment: I call BS on that site. Virtually no computer has eight **bit** pointers, even most micro controllers use 16 bit nowadays. But even if the author's machine honestly did produce that output, that site is atrocious from a pedagogical point of view. Forget that it exists and get a good book.

Comment: I see you were talking about their site. never mind!

Comment: Storing pointers in database columns sounds like a horrible idea; they will not be meaningful from one program invocation to another, much less between separate independent programs that might be accessing the database. Why has nobody pointed this out yet?

Comment: My question is worded wrong. I meant to say the size type of the column. For e.g size of INT type column is 4 bytes. size of TEXT column type is ___?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> per the following code, I get the size of a character pointer is 8 bytes. Yet this site has a size of 1 byte for the char pointer.

It's implementation-defined. It's usually 8 on a 64-bit Intel system and 4 on a 32-bit Intel system. Don't rely on it being any particular size.

> I am writing a connector for a simple database I am implementing and want to read TEXT field of mysql into my database. Since TEXT has variable size, I was wondering if my column can have a fixed size of 8 bytes where I store the pointer in memory to the string (char *)?

It makes no sense at all to store pointers into memory in a database. A database is for persistent data. On the other hand, data stored in memory is liable to disappear whenever a process exits (or the system is restarted).

Comment: Thanks. I was talking about metadata of the column so each column TYPE has a size in bytes. For example column of ints has 4 bytes in size ...

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not. Size of a pointer depends on CPU architecture. Some architecture even have different sizes depending on "type" of the pointer. On x86_64, pointers are 48 bits wide. 64 bits are used because individual bits are not addressable. One could, however, use pointer packing to serialize/deserialize pointers into 48-bit chunks.

Answer (score 1):

A variable can be different sizes based on the computer that you are using. This is causing the discrepancy between your results and the results you see online.

However, the variable will always be the same size on the same machine.

Comment: so is it constant within the context of the machine? So if it is 8 bytes on my machine, I don't expect it to change?

Comment: That's right. It should stay the same size, always, when used under the same conditions (compiler, architecture, processor, etc).

Comment: @Saher It would have a hard time changing while the program is running, since the sizes are compile-time constants. However, compiling the same source code with different compilers (or different configurations of the same compiler) may occasionally give different sizes, along with a host of other differences. Consider compiling code for 32 bit or 64 bit when on a 64 bit machine (most of which can run 32 bit code).

Answer (score 1):

The size of any pointer in one platform is the same.. regardless of the data type char, string, object, etc.
In PC with 64 operating system (and also the compiler support 64 bit), the size of pointer is 8 byte (64 bit address space)..
Another platform may have 4 byte, 2 byte, or 1 byte (like an 8 bit micro controller)..

Comment: Not true. There are some architectures (like old Intel) that use different memory model and have, for example, "far", "near" and "huge" pointers.

Comment: More relevantly to today's computing world, one platform (for certain, very reasonable definitions of "platform") may support multiple ABIs using for example differently-sized address spaces and differently-sized pointers, `long int`s, etc.

Comment: Ok.. what you mean is in term of the 'type' of pointer itself.. in term of type of 'data' the pointer is point to, the size of the pointer is the same..

Comment: True, like in intel 64 bit processor, can still run a 32-bit mode operating system/applications.